# How to retrieve text from a hidden span with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to retrieve the value of a hidden input element from a span tag. I've tried everything found on the web but nothing worked.
Now I am trying the JavascriptExecutor thing:

```
String innerText = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return   arguments[0].innerText", selectedOption);
System.out.println(innerText);
```

But it prints 'null' on the console. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried using getText()?

Comment: Isn't it simply `String value = driver.findElement(By.id("hiddenspanid")).getAttribute("value");`?

Comment: @Purus Yes I've tried getText(), but it only retrieves visible (not hidden) inner text.

Comment: @stealthjong I've tried getAttribute("value") as well, but it gives 'null' too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
String innerText = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", selectedOption);
System.out.println(innerText);
```

So I typed arguments[0].innerHTML in the script instead of arguments[0].innerText.